# Google Analytics: Tracking Status of profiles that have filters

Tags: google-analytics

### My Problem

I have a main Google Analytics profile that tracks all the visits for my site. The tracking has been verified by Google for my main report and those stats are collecting correctly.

I am now trying to create filtered profiles for sub-directories of my site. When I view these profiles they say "**Tracking Not Installed**".

### My Question

Why would Google verify that tracking exists for some profiles and not others?

### What I have already done

1. Made sure UA is correct
2. Checked, using firebug, that when the page is loaded `<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is added to the header
3. Installed GA-Debug in chrome to make sure data is being pushed to Google
4. Checked the setup of my filters to make sure they are correct

### Possible issues

- This is a non-standard installation of GA which calls to multiple UA codes hosted as an external script
- Uses jQuery and there is more than one instance of jQuery being called
- Is working for other sites, this is just an odd case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about the verification. It's only for helping you get started; its not a requirement. (If you were to just begin sending data without verifying, it would just accept the data and not ask you to verify).

In all likelihood, the profile filters for your subdirectories are just misconfigured and are causing *all* traffic to be filtered out. Can you post the details of your configuration?

Comment: You are right, I just checked and all the traffic was filtered out. Thank you for pointing this out :)